# How to pass raw data to post request

Tags: api, go, postman

I have faced some weird issue, I am sending request with Postman (using raw body) and getting correct response, but When I am making request with go, I am getting different response.

I tried this:

```
url := "http://example.com"
payload := strings.NewReader("key=value")
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, payload)
req.Header.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.Header.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36")
req.Header.Add("cache-control", "no-cache")
res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
defer res.Body.Close()
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

fmt.Println(res)
fmt.Println(string(body))
```

But got wrong response, also tried using values

```
values := url.Values{}
values.Add("key", "value")
payload := strings.NewReader(values.Encode())
```

But still getting wrong response, is there a way to simulate postman's raw method in Go?

Postman is automatically adding cookies to my request, just added Cookie header and the problem is fixed

Comment: You should add `Content-Length` header. The postman adds that header under the hood.

Comment: Already tried adding this:
`req.Header.Set("Content-Length", string(len(values.Encode())))`
But still same

Comment: are you checking errors or did you omit them only here for the purpose of brevity?

Comment: @Зелёный That should not be necessary, as [`http.NewReqest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) sets this header for bodies of type `*bytes.Buffer`, `*bytes.Reader`, and `*strings.Reader`. @Paranoid Something you could try to debug this is sending the request to a request bin (e.g. https://requestbin.fullcontact.com/) with go and postman. Looking at the differences might tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Uh, API is not mine and it didn't return any error code, it returns much shorter response than should be

Comment: @Paranoid I meant all the `_` in your code, you're ignoring possible errors.

Comment: @mkopriva oh, I tried, but it's not returning any error

Comment: @Paranoid I second Leon's recommendation about the requestbin, send your request from both postman and go to that service and compare them.

Comment: Thank you guys, seems like Postman was automatically adding cookies, that's why I was receiving different response, thanks a lot

Comment: @Paranoid yes postman is smart enough it saves your cookies and the use it in every request for that url. Try to disable the cookies in the settings of postman and then try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a postman tip: click on the code button/link right below the send button, next to the cookies link and from the popup you can select which language to get code output of the what postman would execute, Go is an option here

For your example I think what you need to do is *remove* the line that explicitly sets the `content-type` to have it match the raw body response in postman